# Start ktor using application.yaml

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I am trying to start ktor using `application.yaml`.

If I try to start it using an embedded server like below, it starts listening on the port defined for the embedded server as expected.

```
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "localhost", module = Application::main)
        .start(wait = true)
}

fun Application.main() {
    install(Koin) {
        slf4jLogger()
        modules(myModule)
    }
    configureRouting()
}
```

But if I change my `main` to:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = EngineMain.main(args)
```

I expected ktor to read the port from `src/resources/application.yaml`:

```
ktor:
  deployment:
    host: "localhost"
    port: 8080
  application:
    modules:
      - com.example.ApplicationKt.main
```

Instead, I get this error:

```
Neither port nor sslPort specified. Use command line options -port/-sslPort or configure connectors in application.conf
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just figured out that it works as expected with `application.conf`, but not with yaml, even though it should be supported according to the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include the `io.ktor:ktor-server-config-yaml` module to make it work:

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-config-yaml")
```